# Summarizing and visualizing a 3d data

Tags: data-visualization

I need a visually appealing way to show 3d data. My data is a demand at time $t$ in region $r$ in scenario $w$, i.e., $d(t, r, w)$. $T$ is $15$, $W$ is $50$, $R$ is $250$.

One example: I can plot $\vert R \vert$ 2d plots with $x$-axis as time and $y$-axis as the demand, each graph will have $\vert W \vert$ scenarios. But this seems too much information, not well summarized.

Comment: Why do you switch from $t$, $r$, and $w$ to $T$, $R$, and $W$?

Comment: @ThePointer it is not a typo. small letters denote indices and capital letters denote the cardinality of the set.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could use a tool like Plotly. Take a look at the examples here: https://plotly.com/python/3d-scatter-plots/